# Google SMTP servers reject my own SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp

I am having a problem with Google's SMTP servers. They reject my SMTP server's IP for no valid reason. My server complies with all the necessary rules to deliver the message but Google rejects it by IP without giving me details and I cannot find support either. I have written to postmaster@gmail.com but got no response. My server sends notifications to the users of the system, it does not do SPAM and apparently everything is correct. I don't see a valid reason for this crash, and I can't find a way to fix it. I would like to know if the same thing happened to someone and how they could solve it. Next I copy the console with the delivery attempt and additionally some DNS checks that show that apparently there is no problem on my server:

```
root@venabili:~# hostname -f
venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
root@venabili:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) grupos=0(root)
root@venabili:~# ifconfig eth0
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 200.69.236.179  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 200.69.236.255
        inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe27:b8e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:16:3e:27:b8:e1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 302342269  bytes 32703331063 (30.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 17  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75025298  bytes 12670842456 (11.8 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@venabili:~# nslookup
> server 8.8.8.8
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
> set type=mx
> tecnologica.com.ar
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
tecnologica.com.ar  mail exchanger = 10 venabili.tecnologica.com.ar.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> set type=a
> venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
Address: 200.69.236.179
> set type=aaaa
> venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
Address: fe80::f816:3eff:fe27:b8e1
> set type=ptr
> 200.69.236.179
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
179.236.69.200.in-addr.arpa name = venabili.tecnologica.com.ar.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> set type=txt
> tecnologica.com.ar
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
tecnologica.com.ar  text = "v=spf1 a mx ip4:200.69.236.179 ip6:fe80::f816:3eff:fe27:b8e1 ~all"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> set type=txt
> default._domainkey.tecnologica.com.ar
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
default._domainkey.tecnologica.com.ar   text = "v=DKIM1; t=s; p=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAz+GrX8vxp9W51ehJuixhL5AbjmCgcN2h7KqMiLI8LMUfmpWPP1GIhxlWCieFUVMOAQGlQrImuFE3kk/qLOgyumzUTRBwxlNX+7tix7dlBclXAWq8SjB9SbbAcPKkTBAq0pvXvp4l4qTCFnfVXAs1g/lCywlJrbfAFVVXWdN44ElFz+bD4YRYsXSmz//L1uFU7YE" "zkFUvbMtwBOL1xRvjAFXH4xQ7/vkHX6+OIxnm47vO/a2CqFVXok0FhAj44BmlBT+Py0x0SP8jsm+xhnLc238ZIsGylTwCb0Zbl3DR9bKGBy9FqXoUyRIzWKEkAtwaKq7qeBO3oRT4kQOKEOog2QIDAQAB"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> _dmarc.tecnologica.com.ar 
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
_dmarc.tecnologica.com.ar   text = "v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:postmaster@tecnologica.com.ar; ruf=mailto:postmaster@tecnologica.com.ar"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> _smtp._tls.tecnologica.com.ar
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
_smtp._tls.tecnologica.com.ar   text = "v=TLSRPTv1; rua=mailto:postmaster@tecnologica.com.ar"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> _mta-sts.tecnologica.com.ar
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
_mta-sts.tecnologica.com.ar text = "v=STSv1; id=20200918192500"

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> set type=cname
> mta-sts.tecnologica.com.ar
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mta-sts.tecnologica.com.ar  canonical name = venabili.tecnologica.com.ar.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
> exit

root@venabili:~# openssl s_client -connect mta-sts.tecnologica.com.ar:443
CONNECTED(00000004)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mta-sts.tecnologica.com.ar
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = mta-sts.tecnologica.com.ar
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = mta-sts.tecnologica.com.ar

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3203 bytes and written 403 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
    Session-ID: 38FDD25BCB4C28F5364CA3418C05D13F279E62882E594190276850599BB67EAB
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 41AEF29EC1545AAE8C53958032EFF464E237232D8AA9D22CF9513297DFFBA40645226685FE58FEC782DA20CDFFEB5EDB
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 5f 78 fa 6f 3a 54 9c c2-f0 8e b2 b7 70 13 05 d4   _x.o:T......p...
    0010 - 4b 39 84 62 c7 cb 96 f8-89 5c 27 09 6c 2b aa ad   K9.b.....\'.l+..
    0020 - 52 22 36 d6 a3 0b 8b 5e-ed 4b 78 f5 49 61 47 69   R"6....^.Kx.IaGi
    0030 - c9 e7 41 88 c2 e6 29 86-b5 52 a9 8f 56 3f 79 3e   ..A...)..R..V?y>
    0040 - 14 bd b5 24 ca c5 f7 a4-ab b9 f9 26 dc 1c 71 7a   ...$.......&..qz
    0050 - ab 5a a2 a9 76 df 61 70-a5 91 5f 69 36 bc 64 69   .Z..v.ap.._i6.di
    0060 - 02 b5 4b ba 79 e0 c9 a7-3b e2 a6 30 9b 2b 34 33   ..K.y...;..0.+43
    0070 - 02 af 1e 3c 82 90 bc ca-32 b3 57 5b e0 b6 33 b0   ...<....2.W[..3.
    0080 - a6 4c dc a8 c9 01 29 cf-98 ba 7c 40 3a ae 4b 04   .L....)...|@:.K.
    0090 - 95 66 2f 96 b2 b9 5b f1-b0 f2 b0 6c e4 61 6f d0   .f/...[....l.ao.
    00a0 - 98 a2 67 06 c9 22 ef a3-f5 ec 24 ac a2 b1 5f 4e   ..g.."....$..._N

    Start Time: 1600571394
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
GET /.well-known/mta-sts.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: venabili.tecnologica.com.ar

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2020 03:10:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 77
Last-Modified: Sat, 19 Sep 2020 14:07:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5f6610b2-4d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

version: STSv1
mode: testing
mx: venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
max_age: 604800
^C
root@venabili:~# openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect venabili.tecnologica.com.ar:587 -crlf -ign_eof
CONNECTED(00000004)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = venabili.tecnologica.com.ar

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3389 bytes and written 432 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
250 CHUNKING
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: D8A0F5C48FBFE47FAEF6482AC696CBCAB01EB030F683053A41539DCD5B91E593
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: 3CACF3832764ACCF8A00FFDAFA9A8771E62C04FCDF1429A85EB2A3AC0F39733F642045E4602CE73F62AEC75745B51392
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 30 00 51 89 4c df 15 62-da 50 55 37 92 60 65 f2   0.Q.L..b.PU7.`e.
    0010 - 05 72 39 3d fb 1e 8a 05-2f 95 6b f0 cd 33 29 b0   .r9=..../.k..3).
    0020 - b7 38 89 4f 2f 32 91 66-f7 59 2f 80 43 fc 81 f7   .8.O/2.f.Y/.C...
    0030 - c6 53 68 3d d8 69 0d 10-6c 4c 62 9c 81 d9 ec 60   .Sh=.i..lLb....`
    0040 - 9f ef a0 95 46 d3 e0 10-29 09 20 ab 48 3b 07 34   ....F...). .H;.4
    0050 - 82 d3 0e 39 3d 11 18 e8-9e 44 b7 69 b9 d0 45 2e   ...9=....D.i..E.
    0060 - 97 4f da 69 aa 89 27 2c-e5 9c 63 39 4b f8 3f 54   .O.i..',..c9K.?T
    0070 - 23 1a db 73 ac 7e 78 20-76 f5 67 b9 8f e1 c3 34   #..s.~x v.g....4
    0080 - d7 f0 b5 0b 0d c7 dc 80-f6 40 0c 20 3f 8d 16 b7   .........@. ?...
    0090 - 3a c2 e2 a9 c1 b6 fd 84-65 7f a5 1c 16 81 60 5a   :.......e.....`Z
    00a0 - 53 12 3a bf d0 4a 0c 0e-a2 3b 57 ce ad 63 89 e6   S.:..J...;W..c..
    00b0 - a7 58 ea 21 f9 2e 04 00-ff 6f a7 40 9d 2c bf 39   .X.!.....o.@.,.9
    00c0 - 8d d9 19 c9 e1 05 a6 19-a4 60 06 75 8d 3e 95 89   .........`.u.>..

    Start Time: 1600567929
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
ehlo venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
250-venabili.tecnologica.com.ar
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250-SMTPUTF8
250 CHUNKING
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
bm8tcmVzcG9uZGVyQHRlY25vbG9naWNhLmNvbS5hcg==
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
!!!
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
mail from: no-responder@tecnologica.com.ar
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: jmouriz@gmail.com 
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
from: root <no-responder@tecnologica.com.ar>
to: Juan Manuel Mouriz <jmouriz@gmail.com>
subject: Mensaje de prueba

Hola, este es un mensaje de prueba
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 5E50844853
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
closed
root@venabili:~# grep 5E50844853 /var/log/mail.log
Sep 19 23:18:54 venabili postfix/submission/smtpd[7994]: 5E50844853: client=venabili.tecnologica.com.ar[200.69.236.179], sasl_method=login, sasl_username=no-responder@tecnologica.com.ar
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/cleanup[8543]: 5E50844853: message-id=<20200920021854.5E50844853@venabili.tecnologica.com.ar>
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/qmgr[5677]: 5E50844853: from=<no-responder@tecnologica.com.ar>, size=554, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/cleanup[8543]: 6F3BE4485D: message-id=<20200920021854.5E50844853@venabili.tecnologica.com.ar>
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili amavis[26666]: (26666-19) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOutbound}, ORIGINATING LOCAL [200.69.236.179]:55833 [200.69.236.179] <no-responder@tecnologica.com.ar> -> <jmouriz@gmail.com>, Queue-ID: 5E50844853, Message-ID: <20200920021854.5E50844853@venabili.tecnologica.com.ar>, mail_id: bcEyyqxUQvNK, Hits: -1, size: 554, queued_as: 6F3BE4485D, dkim_new=default:tecnologica.com.ar, 329 ms
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/smtp[8676]: 5E50844853: to=<jmouriz@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=115, delays=115/0.02/0.01/0.32, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10027): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6F3BE4485D)
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/qmgr[5677]: 5E50844853: removed
root@venabili:~# grep 6F3BE4485D /var/log/mail.log
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/smtpd[8679]: 6F3BE4485D: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/cleanup[8543]: 6F3BE4485D: message-id=<20200920021854.5E50844853@venabili.tecnologica.com.ar>
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/qmgr[5677]: 6F3BE4485D: from=<no-responder@tecnologica.com.ar>, size=1625, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili amavis[26666]: (26666-19) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOutbound}, ORIGINATING LOCAL [200.69.236.179]:55833 [200.69.236.179] <no-responder@tecnologica.com.ar> -> <jmouriz@gmail.com>, Queue-ID: 5E50844853, Message-ID: <20200920021854.5E50844853@venabili.tecnologica.com.ar>, mail_id: bcEyyqxUQvNK, Hits: -1, size: 554, queued_as: 6F3BE4485D, dkim_new=default:tecnologica.com.ar, 329 ms
Sep 19 23:20:35 venabili postfix/smtp[8676]: 5E50844853: to=<jmouriz@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=115, delays=115/0.02/0.01/0.32, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10027): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6F3BE4485D)
Sep 19 23:20:37 venabili postfix/smtp[8680]: 6F3BE4485D: to=<jmouriz@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.192.26]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.02/0.02/0.88/0.8, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.192.26] said: 550-5.7.1 [200.69.236.179] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your 550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at 550 5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NotAuthorizedError a44si4686321qtk.87 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Sep 19 23:20:37 venabili postfix/bounce[8681]: 6F3BE4485D: sender non-delivery notification: 32EF64485E
Sep 19 23:20:37 venabili postfix/qmgr[5677]: 6F3BE4485D: removed
root@venabili:~#
```

The domain in question is tecnologica.com.ar and I leave a link to some verifications where it is seen that the RR SPF, DKIM, DMARC, _SMTP._TLS, _MTA-STS, MTA-STS, CAA and PTR are correct and it is not a open relay:

https://mxtoolbox.com/domain/tecnologica.com.ar

The certificates are signed by Let's Encrypt. The host name matches the certificate. The classes are correct. And finally, I do not SPAM. I would greatly appreciate a help because at this point I am completely disoriented and can't find what else to do.

I am not looking for a solution but rather where I can find it.

Thank you very much for your help

## Additional info

This is a report domain for DMARC:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>7762784093316082866</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1603756800</begin>
      <end>1603843199</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>tecnologica.com.ar</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>reject</p>
    <sp>reject</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>200.69.236.179</source_ip>
      <count>2</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>pass</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>tecnologica.com.ar</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>tecnologica.com.ar</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
        <selector>default</selector>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>tecnologica.com.ar</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>
```

And this is a report domain for TLS:

```json
{"organization-name":"Google Inc.","date-range":{"start-datetime":"2020-10-26T00:00:00Z","end-datetime":"2020-10-26T23:59:59Z"},"contact-info":"smtp-tls-reporting@google.com","report-id":"2020-10-26T00:00:00Z_tecnologica.com.ar","policies":[{"policy":{"policy-type":"sts","policy-string":["version: STSv1\r","mode: testing\r","mx: venabili.tecnologica.com.ar\r","max_age: 604800\r","\r"],"policy-domain":"tecnologica.com.ar"},"summary":{"total-successful-session-count":1,"total-failure-session-count":0}}]}
```

Comment: From which SMTP are you sending your emails from? Is that SMTP server configured with SFP and DKIM?

Comment: Thanks @architjn Yes, of course, I am sending from a SMTP with SPF and DKIM as seen above

Comment: You must be receiving fail reports from google at `postmaster@tecnologica.com.ar`. Could you share the XML included in that email.

Comment: @JuanManuel have you already found a solution for this ? or some kind of workaround, like, setting up something on postfix to relay Only to gmail, and the other communication flows normally ?

Comment: @mf_ I didn't really find the solution, I also don't know where to look for it.  Finally I am using sendgrid specifically for GMail

Comment: @JuanManuel is that a conditional configuration ? how to do that setup ? is it in postfix ?